# Do I need travel itinerary for my parents for a Canadian Temporary Resident Visa application?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada

My parents are in India and I am in Canada. I am planning to apply for Canada TRV (visitor) for my parents online. They are planning to visit me in April-June 2017 for three months. The online application asks for uploading of proof of travel (either flight tickets or travel itinerary).

1. Do I need to buy travel itinerary?
2. If I file application for my parents from Canada, where do I need to send the passports for TRV stamping, Canada or India?

Answer (score 1):

In general, while it might be you who is pressing the buttons, for all intents and purposes it's your parents who are applying for a visa.

With that said:

1. No one needs to buy anything. They need to provide proof they intend to return after those three months, however. Ties to the country etc. A return ticket is helpful as one piece of proof but not a requirement.
2. You do not file anything. You might be the one who is footing the bills and provide accommodation and your parents will need that in writing but you do not file a thing. Your parents do and they file at their residence, so India.